# Fix a UnicodeEncodeError caused by smart quotes

Tags: python, django, unicode, latex

I am working on a project that involves auto-generating documents (via latex). The person creating these documents is working on a windows machine (he was working with Microsoft word but now he is editing them in notepad). Anyways, I noticed that sometimes after he edits the documents, the whole generation process fails because of Python UnicodeEncodeError.

I tracked down the problem to sets of quotes and apostraphes he has is adding to the document.
I have read a lot about this error, but I am not sure what the best way to solve this problem is in python.

It is a Django App, so I tried using force_unicode, smart_str, etc. from django.utils.encode, but this did not work. I have no clue why the characters he is adding are different then characters I am adding on the different operating system.

Can someone please

1. explain what is going on
2. suggestion the best solution to the problem

Comment: Post some sourcecode - you haven't provided enough technical details. What generates the UnicodeEncodeError? How does the windows edited doc get processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excellent chance that the problematic quotes are using the nonstandard [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) codepoint assignments.  Try changing all instances of "latin1" and/or "iso-8859-1" in your django app to "windows-1252".

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to solve this problem without seeing some code. But in my experience, nine times out of ten unicode errors in Django are caused by a `__unicode__` method that doesn't actually don't return Unicode.

For example:

```
def __unicode__(self):
   return 'foo %s' % self.bar
```

Because the string is a bytestring, not a unicode, this will break horribly whenever the `bar` field contains text from outside ASCII. It should be:

```
   return u'foo %s' % self.bar
```